# Rigify Question

Tags: rigging, bones, weight-painting, rigify

I'm fairly new to animation. I've been using Blender for sometime now but not in a regular basis. This is the first time I try to rig a character using rigify

My character is a scientist that wears glasses, has a moustache and some hair.

Of elements are not moving at the same pace than others, thus I'm getting a stretching effect I'm not after

[image]

For the glasses I used weight paint to ensure that it has 100% influence... it worked for the frame, but the lenses do not move along. What am I missing?

Comment: Hi. Please make the title of your question specific to the problem you are having and not just the general topic. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like something to do with weight painting but it's hard to say for sure. Sharing the file can help troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I fixed this by removing additional weight maps created by automatic weighting. Took me a while to figure this out. All good now!